# "Утеря" или "утрата"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Утеря* или *утрата* трудовой книжки? Я больше склоняюсь к первому варианту, но часто встречается второй.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опять же, разный смысл. Утеря говорит о конкретном способе пропажи - человек трудовую книжку потерял. А вот утрата - более широкое понятие. Он мог ее и потерять, у него ее могли украсть, а могла сгрызть собака.